# How to copy a list into another in a StateNotifier, so it update with every change

Tags: flutter, dart, state, riverpod

The List EleccionSinSeleccionClase is just a list of a class who has a String on it.

```
class EleccionSinSeleccionClase {
  String Eleccion;
}
```

The state List is another class:

```
class EleccionConSleccionClase {
  String Eleccion;
  bool selec;
}
```

The problem is that I want to copy the first into the state of the StateNotifier, this line break the code.
This is the line: **state[i].Eleccion = ListaElecciones[i].Eleccion;**

```
class EleccionesConSeleccionNotifier
    extends StateNotifier<List<EleccionConSleccionClase>> {
  final List<EleccionSinSeleccionClase> ListaElecciones;

  EleccionesConSeleccionNotifier({required this.ListaElecciones}) : super([]);

  void init(){
    print(ListaElecciones.length.toString());
    if(ListaElecciones.length != 0){
      for (int i = 0; i < ListaElecciones.length; i++) {
        state[i].Eleccion = ListaElecciones[i].Eleccion;  ////HERE////
      }
    }
  }
}

final eleccionConSleccionStateNotifierProvider = StateNotifierProvider<
    EleccionesConSeleccionNotifier, List<EleccionConSleccionClase>>((ref) {
  final eleccioneswatch =
      ref.watch(eleccionesSinSeleccionStateNotifierProvider);

  return EleccionesConSeleccionNotifier(ListaElecciones: eleccioneswatch)..init();
});
```

Comment: please avoid using variables name starting with CAPITAL LETTER !!

Comment: and ``state[i].Eleccion = ListaElecciones[i].Eleccion;  ////HERE////`` line shows what error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the problem is that you initialize state as an empty list `super([])` and then you're trying to change a value in an index that doesn't exist (`state[i]` where the list is obviously empty and cannot access that position)

```
void init(){
    print(ListaElecciones.length.toString());
    if(ListaElecciones.length != 0){
      /// you will need to check if both lists are the same lenght if you actually want to do this
      /// without failling
      /*for (int i = 0; i < ListaElecciones.length; i++) {
        state[i].Eleccion = ListaElecciones[i].Eleccion;  ////HERE////
      }*/
      /// if you only want to copy Eleccion parameter in a new class this would be the easiest way
      state = ListaElecciones.map((cb) => EleccionConSleccionClase(Eleccion: cb.Eleccion)).toList();
    }
  }
```